# object required error

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I'm trying to implement a function that will disable the `cmdButton7` when checkbox `checkMultiple` is checked. and enable it again when `sum = 100` using vbscript , asp.net.

I tried the method below:

Sub disableButton() 
If document.form1.Multiple.value = 1 Then
document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = False
ElseIf sum = 100 Then
document.form1.cmdButton7.enabled = true
End If 
End Sub

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkMultiple" id="Multiple" onclick="disableButton">Multiple</input>
```

But I get this error:
object required "disableButton"

Comment: "on" appears in that several places... doh!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to solve object required error. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081655/how-to-solve-object-required-error)

Answer (score 1):

Add a space between "Multiple" and onclick in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkMultiple" id="Multiple" onclick="disableButton">Multiple</input>
```

For this error, the string "Multiple" and onclick attribute needs a space between them.

Comment: Now having the product Required "disableButton" error.<br>

Name: disableButton        value: Empty